# Why return to String need so many operations when develop a smart contract?

Tags: opcode

I found a smart contract. The address is '0x2fabe69843e9a74a35b89145cb52e5568986c7a1'.

I am really confused about is that why it need over 3000 lines Opcode to when Created this smart contract? Like some operation 'Balance' it didn't show in the Source Code.

How to analyze the Opcode based on the  Source Code 
The Source code is below:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.11;

contract IMG{


    function IMG(){

    }

    function read() returns(string){

        return "FF D8 FF E0 00 10 4A 46 49 46 00 01 01 00 00 01 00 01 00 00 FF DB 00 84 00 28 28 28 28 2B 28 2D 32 32 2D 3F 44 3C 44 3F 5D 55 4E 4E 55 5D 8C 64 6C 64 6C 64 8C D5 85 9B 85 85 9B 85 D5 BC E4 B9 AD B9 E4 BC FF FF EB EB FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF 01 28 28 28 28 2B 28 2D 32 32 2D 3F 44 3C 44 3F 5D 55 4E 4E 55 5D 8C 64 6C 64 6C 64 8C D5 85 9B 85 85 9B 85 D5 BC E4 B9 AD B9 E4 BC FF FF EB EB FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF C0 00 11 08 00 80 00 80 03 01 22 00 02 11 01 03 11 01 FF C4 00 6C 00 00 02 03 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 03 04 00 01 02 05 10 00 02 02 01 03 04 01 04 03 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 02 11 03 12 21 31 04 13 41 51 61 14 22 23 42 32 62 71 B1 01 01 01 01 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 02 03 11 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 11 21 02 31 51 FF DA 00 0C 03 01 00 02 11 03 11 00 3F 00 7C 85 30 11 CC 9F 27 07 53 04 29 3B 2C 08 51 08 04 21 08 04 21 0A 02 C8 42 80 B2 88 40 21 08 50 00 EE 48 07 EE C7 B4 21 7C D0 AA 68 D6 C5 48 C9 AF F0 32 98 BA FF 00 4D 53 5E 51 03 1A D1 76 80 46 B8 34 F6 08 2D A2 5A 17 73 33 DC 18 1A 2C 5A 39 53 B2 D6 52 E2 19 A2 52 00 B2 7C 11 E5 A7 43 03 1A 51 7A 50 A7 D4 04 8E 6B 18 74 7D 31 26 98 83 D7 23 2E 6D 72 C7 0E B3 DD 89 52 94 65 16 81 F6 4A ED 31 C5 61 3F 46 B6 F4 8A 94 5C 4C D8 56 CA 77 5B 92 0A 4C D6 8F 0D 84 44 B6 D4 56 26 E5 BF 80 D3 8B 78 DA 46 63 50 82 44 18 8B 50 96 44 09 34 D2 51 37 CF 92 94 6A CA 37 07 6A D7 00 BB 92 D7 A4 62 15 54 0E 10 FC ED BE 06 98 AC 97 15 60 D5 3A A7 4F 90 B9 93 7B 24 E8 03 8B F0 20 61 64 69 03 72 DC CA BA A3 51 AF 20 3A 41 3E EC 89 DD 90 C3 4C E4 DE 0C 4A D4 6D B0 DD D6 D5 01 58 96 57 BF 02 70 17 BF 05 01 07 97 34 DE C3 F9 FA 78 C3 0D C2 22 53 7A 31 AA 2C C4 B5 B5 9F 3E 2A D6 9D 0F B8 AC 98 B5 2E 1A 38 FA F2 CD 69 B6 D1 D6 C1 3D 18 61 01 EA 48 79 B6 A9 41 AA 33 38 B7 B2 18 BF 26 7B 91 4C C6 D6 B1 23 8D C6 22 73 EA A3 09 34 B7 61 FA 9C ED C3 44 0E 5C 23 A6 DB 46 E4 D6 6D B0 67 D4 E4 93 FE 21 F1 F5 38 E5 B3 54 C5 5F 53 36 AA A2 65 AD 51 4D 72 6A F9 8C CA E8 4D 24 DB 45 25 68 1C BA 6C CA 09 A6 0E 12 9C 5D 48 CB 4E 96 94 56 88 97 A9 13 52 32 A5 F2 AB D9 18 57 1D 86 52 5B B6 2D 91 A9 3E 4A 0B 0C B3 5E 42 D6 39 FF 00 2C 11 15 8A 7A 92 1B 8C B7 5E 59 29 8D 68 BF D5 46 3E 12 10 73 8F 71 AD 47 5A 3F 27 37 AB E9 E1 1F CB 01 0D 62 79 12 5B CC 98 57 71 8B E1 C5 DF 92 4D 9D 8C 38 31 61 5F 69 AB 38 6E 52 D3 C4 D4 D4 90 69 C3 0E 48 FD F0 09 92 5A 39 4E 80 AC 8B C7 06 3A BF 4B 7D 27 4B EE 61 A0 B0 62 A7 1C 66 72 71 A8 0B 6D EE 6F B5 30 79 75 36 2F 26 A4 B7 2A DB 75 46 96 36 B6 03 5A 24 4D 12 F6 34 53 E0 9A 61 59 CA 55 B3 07 0C 6D BB 61 92 B4 EC D2 D8 2A A1 8D 26 34 B4 C7 60 29 A2 F5 7C 90 30 E7 4B 81 1C F9 B6 68 C6 5C AD 6C 85 9E 39 4B 79 1A 91 04 E9 B2 51 D3 8E 4B F1 67 1B B7 28 F0 12 19 DA 74 CD 59 A8 EB 6B 8F 87 40 67 04 FF 00 AF FC 06 B2 36 4B 66 1A 54 A2 E9 AB 14 B7 17 BA 63 8D 58 09 5D D3 42 01 AC CB D0 7C 6F DB 16 9E 3F 46 61 91 C5 9A 47 4F 51 7A 91 44 D8 C3 58 06 4D 9E A4 C1 77 02 E4 DC 5B B3 E9 96 58 65 30 A5 65 49 FC 80 ED 4D 71 23 32 86 5F 65 E2 77 F0 C2 A6 C2 3A 13 83 C9 17 BA 36 F2 BB E1 8C 07 69 0B CE 09 98 96 67 E9 99 EE 4B D3 35 89 AD A9 4E 21 63 95 BF 1B 80 52 6F F5 61 62 FF 00 AB 00 FA AC A7 2F 0C CD FC 03 7A BD 11 56 EF C0 27 BF 3C 9A 4D F9 4C A9 4B C5 15 1D 32 99 08 72 74 09 99 A3 6C C8 54 A2 9A 34 5D 00 3A 29 A3 74 53 03 14 BD 15 48 D9 28 0C D2 2D 23 5A 4B A0 2A 8A 68 D1 90 2A 8A A3 44 03 FF D9";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Most of the bytes in the code of this contract belong to the `.data` section where the constant string is stored (returned by `read`).

You can use http://remix.ethereum.org to compile the contract, view the assembly and trace the transaction step by step.

Comment: I am really confused is why the how to connect the instructions with the source code? I tried Remix, but I am still confused about how to connect  each step with the source code. Thank you.

Comment: You can deploy the contract, then press on the debug button. It will open the transaction in the debugger and you can step through it.

Answer (score 0):

The long hexadecimal string is not OpCode. From the first few bytes, "FF D8 FF E0", this is the [signature](https://www.filesignatures.net/index.php?page=search&search=FFD8FFE0&mode=SIG) of JPEG files. The contract essentially stores the raw bytes of a picture.

If the data is valid, one can save it as a JPEG file to restore the picture. However, one needs to be careful before trusting and viewing the data. See also [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/181594/195541).